# Task Software with Daily Email

Tags: productivity

I'm looking for a task list application with one main feature:

> It can send a daily email at a specified time with all the tasks due that day and overdue. Bonus if it can also include tasks approaching their due date.

I have not been able to find one yet that has this feature - I've tried Any.do, Todoist, Wunderlist, and many others. Could be I've looked in the wrong place though.

They often have the ability to send per task reminders, but that results in too many emails for me.

Other requirements - these would be nice, but not necessary:

- Windows and/or Web app
- Android app
- Sub-tasks
- Recuring tasks

Gratis is preferred, but a not overly large payment would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wrike](https://www.wrike.com/) (paid) has that ability, they call it [Daily To-Do Emails](https://help.wrike.com/hc/en-us/articles/209605589-Daily-To-Do-Emails):

> The Daily To-do email is made up of two sections:
>
> - Tasks for Today—shows active tasks which are assigned to you and whose due date meets one of three criteria: today’s date falls between the task’s scheduled start and due dates, today’s date is one of the start or due dates, or the task is overdue (the scheduled due date has already passed).
> - Overdue Tasks Created by You—shows active tasks which you created and whose due date has passed. Tasks in this section are not necessarily assigned to you, but they were created by you.

I also noticed that [Hubspot](https://www.hubspot.com/) has [Daily Overdue Task Emails](https://www.hubspot.com/product-updates/projects-overdue-tasks). I could not quickly [find](https://www.google.com/search?q=email+tasks+to+do+site%3Ahubspot.com) if they also can mail "today's tasks", and you would have to investigate if this is in their free or paid plans.

Then there is [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) which lets you

> ... create automated workflows between your favorite apps and services to get notifications

but that may get a bit complicated to setup: [Sending one reminder for multiple tasks](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Sending-one-reminder-for-multiple-tasks/m-p/150723).

Tip: [Google for 'email overdue tasks'](https://www.google.com/search?q=email+overdue+tasks) to find more possible solutions.

Comment: Wrike looks very interesting, thank you @Jan. Also they do seem to have a free plan, and the page you linked says the capability is available for all account types. I will give it a go and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Wrike an Agile tool which supports reminders, tasks and subtasks, and "approaching due date" but 99% doesn't let you choose when to send reminders.
www.wrike.com

Most apps do not let you choose *when* to send reminders, unless you go with the most expensive Corporate/Enterprise plan.

Below you can see an example of a Wrike daily reminder with many overdue tasks
[image: Wrike daily reminder]

Comment: The other answer already mentions Wrike, what more do you have to add?

Comment: My answer contains proof of the daily reminder, which was asked by an admin.
Moreover my previous and earlier answer was deleted by an admin for lack of a screenshot. I don't understand how this version of stackexchange works, but since you offer a reward than I believe it is my right to seek it as original poster of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try zappier you can integrate it with different apps one of which is trello

Explore Ways to Use Schedule by Zapier Set up recurring goals or to-dos Too many things to remember? Zapier helps you get to your recurring tasks without missing a beat. Schedule recurring Monday Trello cards so that you can dive right back into your workflow.

https://zapier.com/